# Display spans inline-block combined with inline

Tags: html, css

If you have three span elementshow do you display them like this?

```
span1_______         span3
            |||||||||
            |||||||||

            span2
```

span1 is inline-block width adjusted
span2 is inline-block margin-top adjusted
span3 is inline

But span2 pulls down span1 and span2 down with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds right-- the margin is probably pushing the block-level container that holds all three of them.  You may consider instead trying `position: relative` on span2 and changing it's `margin-top` to just `top`.

Answer (score 0):

if i did understand correctly what you want. you might try using `transform:translateY(npx)` or you can use `%`

see example :

```css
span:nth-child(2){
 position:relative;
transform:translateY(10px);
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>span1</span>
<span>span2</span>
<span>span3</span>
```

OR a way to achieve your example ( with that black line ), is using this css

```css
span:nth-child(2){
  width:100px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>span1</span>
<span></span>
<span>span3</span>
```